# What is the default path of debug.keystore on Mac?

Tags: android

I am a new Mac user. I searched everywhere for `debug.keystore` file, but no luck. Is it possible that eclipse can't create the file?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The default location is `/Users/<username>/.android/debug.keystore`.

Go into Finder, navigate to your home directory, then press Command+Shift+G and in the pop-up type `.android` - you'll see all files there.

Comment: Oh, .android folder didn't seem under /Users/userName. And search didn't help, because .android is hidden. But CMD + Shift + G worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14):

should be here:

```
~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Comment: Thank you, actually I knew the default folder, but I didn't know how to show hidden folders.

Answer (score 2):

Using the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> I found the files in .android directory, but for mac I found no *"debug.keystore"* file rather I found *"debug.keyset".*

Being not so sure, but I deleted this one and clean and build my app, now its working for me.

Comment: I did this in the finder and it opened up a prompt to enter the folder location you wanted to go to.  This was extremely helpful!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal found in Finder > Applications > Utilities
In Terminal, paste the following: defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
Press return
Hold ‘alt’ on your keyboard, then right click on the Finder icon in the dock and click Relaunch.