# Google login with cordova won't work. Error 10 in Android and bad request in IOS

Tags: javascript, macos, cordova, authentication, google-api

I have a Android/IOS app build with cordova.

As I'm running the server with ssl now, I can't open with the inappBrowser the requests from google. So I have to use the native login, with [this](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) plugin. ( Which is the most reliable that I have found )

After reading many posts ( [this](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/404), [this](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/260), and [..](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2352379) ) I believe that the problem it's in the way I am (trying to) generate my key file

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v -alias myAppName
```

(with empty password ) it prompts

```
error de herramienta de claves: java.lang.Exception: El alias <myAppName> no existe (doesn't exist)
java.lang.Exception: El alias <myAppName> no existe
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doPrintEntry(Main.java:1738)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1064)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:343)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:336)
```

Does that mean it didn't work?

About the error:

```
window.plugins.googleplus.login(
    {
      'scopes': 'profile email', 
      'webClientId': 'xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com', 
      'offline': true, 
    },
    function (obj) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(obj)); /
    },
    function (msg) {
      alert('error: ' + msg); // <--- It alerts 'error: 10'
    }
);
```

[image]

Any hint would be very welcome

-EDIT (this is now solved)-

Just tested in IOS (simulator) and the result is even worse:
[image]

-EDIT 2-

I tried to install it both ways ( same result )

- `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --save --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid`
- `cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus --save --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid`

( And multiple times, before and after "setting" the .key )

-EDIT 3-

BTW, What does this error mean? ( can't find it, either )

Comment: This issue (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/243) provides many different solutions (which seem to work for all of the users) for that problem. Have you tried all of them?

Comment: I read that one, too. It links to a solution. But my problem is that its not working even in development. I think my problem is the way I'm generating my certs..

Comment: Check if your debug.keystore is in the default directory (assuming you are working on a mac): https://stackoverflow.com/a/7529858/6184203

Comment: Thanks! yes, it's in: `/Users/toni/.android/debug.keystore`

Comment: Then continue reading here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925659/keytool-alias-does-not-exist

Comment: Sorry, the same info there.. Do you mean that I should use a different path or.. ?

Comment: Yes you should try a few different things. There are so many answers on this topic.

Comment: @David i know.. i might have read them all... I think this article linked in the first URL you commented has the answers. But I can't find those pages in the google console.. ( already asked the author but still waiting for reply.. )

Comment: This page: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials or the App-signing page in the developer console?

Comment: please post your `GoogleService-Info.plist`.  Also in my project I don't use `'scopes': 'profile email', `

Comment: @MaximShoustin Thanks for writing. I don't seem to find a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file. In which folder should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't seem to find a GoogleService-Info.plist file. In which folder should it be?

Since we talk about iOS I believe `GoogleService-Info.plist` file is missing and this is a problem. Please take a look on this [EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/blob/master/README.md#ios)

> To get your iOS REVERSED_CLIENT_ID, generate a configuration file here. This GoogleService-Info.plist file contains the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID you'll need during installation. This value is only needed for iOS.
>
> The REVERSED_CLIENT_ID is also known as the "iOS URL Scheme" on the Developer's Console.
>
> Login on iOS takes the user to a SafariViewController through the Google SDK, instead of the separate Safari browser.

To generate a configuration file go to:  [https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=ios](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=ios&cntapi=signin)

Locate this file in root of your iOS project

---

In my case the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>18643434937-j6ofvkktk1uklqjv61ecr75f1llqki0f.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <key>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.18643434937-j6ofvkktk1uklqjv61ecr75f1llqki0f</string>
    <key>PLIST_VERSION</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>BUNDLE_ID</key>
    <string>com.app.client</string>
    <key>PROJECT_ID</key>
    <string>app-c6c82</string>
    <key>IS_ADS_ENABLED</key>
    <false/>
    <key>IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED</key>
    <false/>
    <key>IS_APPINVITE_ENABLED</key>
    <false/>
    <key>IS_GCM_ENABLED</key>
    <false/>
    <key>IS_SIGNIN_ENABLED</key>
    <true/>
    <key>GOOGLE_APP_ID</key>
    <string>1:68743434937:ios:b03bcd3b3f571a56</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

---

For Android `google-services.json`:

Go to: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android

and generate it there.

It should look like:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "68643434935",
    "project_id": "myapp-c6c82"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:68643434935:android:71bc3a4035ab9002",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.agan.armoa"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "68643434935-mqm5s8lubfr5j5s3bj62eigbod0h083s.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.agan.armoa",
            "certificate_hash": "759A66458E30A70628F2E6A66C46240E21676B72"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "68643434935-bc48465luu0r77tufpf4fumv0bd5pta2.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        },
        {
          "client_id": "68643434935-gpdj67581deilm3refkgobuvneceisqt.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyDB6g1-nMbZ9aZkic2dCz8QrcqHfCSDrsw"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:68643434935:android:b03bcd3b3f571a56",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.myapp.client"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "68643434935-25ciu2gccfv70m08sc7c4fr3v0gqe89m.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.myapp.client",
            "certificate_hash": "E90A75A9AA4470337AE5ECD87C3416DDB1109BE1"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "68643434935-bc48465luu0r77tufpf4fumv0bd5pta2.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        },
        {
          "client_id": "68643434935-gpdj67581deilm3refkgobuvneceisqt.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyDB6g1-nMbZ9aZkic2dCz8QrcqHfCSDrsw"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

---

**[EDIT 2]**

About your error:

> keytool -exportcert -list -v \ -alias project -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore I get this error: error de herramienta de claves: java.lang.Exception: El archivo de almacén de claves no existe: /Users/toni/.android/debug.keystore java.lang.Exception: El archivo de almacén de claves no existe: /Users/toni/.android/debug.keystore

Try to run:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US"
```

to generate `~/.android/debug.keystore`

Also take a look: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/index.html#debugmode

**[EDIT 3]**

`error 10` means:

> public static final int DEVELOPER_ERROR
>
> The application is misconfigured. This error is not recoverable and
> will be treated as fatal. The developer should look at the logs after
> this to determine more actionable information.
>
> Constant Value: 10

See [DOCS](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#INTERNAL_ERROR) and similar error solution:  [Error: Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273145/error-statusstatuscode-developer-error-resolution-null)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the thing is that it generated different id/reverse_id than I use in the website. is that a problem? also, in which folder of the cordova project should I place the file?

Comment: You should use what is generated. The file should be located under  `PROGECT_ROOT/platforms/ios/<ProjectName>/` in my case its `~/projects/moodo/platforms/ios/Moodo/GoogleService-Info.plist` (next to `Classes`)

Comment: Generally you register ios app on Google Console

Comment: After saving the GoogleService-Info.plist in the project path under `platforms/ios/project` it's working in IOS! So thanks for that! :D but same error ( error 10 ) in Android.. any clue about the android 10 error?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet do you have `google-services.json` file inside Android Project?

Comment: No, should it look like this? ( just downloaded from the google credentials page) `{"web":{"client_id":"xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"api-project-xxxxxx","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"nyK_io3qRNK_OgOcEceKTLC4","redirect_uris":["https://project.com/google.php","http://project.com/google.php","https://beta.project.com/google.php"],"javascript_origins":["https://project.com","https://beta.project.com"]}}`

Comment: If you checkout my original question I had trouble generating/setting/dunnoWhat my keys: when I type: `keytool -exportcert -list -v \

-alias project -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore` I get this error:  `error de herramienta de claves: java.lang.Exception: El archivo de almacén de claves no existe: /Users/toni/.android/debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: El archivo de almacén de claves no existe: /Users/toni/.android/debug.keystore` ( in english mean that they key is not found ) very frustrating..

Comment: Thanks for your last edit. I was able to generate de debug.keystore and entered in the google certificate page. Downloaded de json file and placed into `/platforms/android` tried to run the app in device. Still got `error 10` :(

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet check in logs that you have following logs: `"Building Google options"`, `"Building GoogleApiClient"`, `"GoogleApiClient built"`. Also reinstall up to start from beginning. Post also logs you see on Android related to google plus

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet added EDIT 3, see error description

Comment: In the `cordoba build android` log from the terminal you mean? if so, no, there isn't any of this 3 logs ( even removing and installing the plugin).. ( thank for letting me know the description of the error.. turns out I'm the error :P )

Comment: Well, I don't see the logs. But finally it's working in Android and IOS (seems like reinstalling with the google.json it was enoguh). Thank you SO MUCH for your help!

Answer (score 8):

For me error 10 happened when the generated SHA1 by keytool(which i used to add the app to google) mismatched with the build apk's sha 1. How i fixed is by editing the SHA1 of the google project to the build apks SHA1.

1 - first, build the apk

```
cordova build android --device --verbose --stacktrace --debug
```

2 - see path to your apk. it will be in projectfolder/platforms/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

3 - get the SHA1 of the apk

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile <path to your apk>
```

it will output the details which include SHA1. copy this and replace the SHA1 in google project app.

4 - go to firebase console open app edit the SHA1. copy the build apk's SHA1 to replace the previous SHA1 which we initially pasted on when creating the app.

Comment: this solution save my day

Comment: happy to hear that :)

Comment: Worked perfectly in 2022! I missed out the Step 3 and as soon as I did that, the Error 10 issue resolved immediately. Thanks a ton for sharing!