# unable to google sign in error code 10 as a response from google using cordova plugin

Tags: angularjs, html, cordova

```
if (window.plugins)
    window.plugins.googleplus.login({
            'scopes': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login 
             https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
```

// optional, space-separated list of scopes, If not included or empty, defaults to `profile and`email`.
                'webClientId': 'myclientid', // optional clientId of your Web application from Credentials settings of your project - On Android, this MUST be included to get an idToken. On iOS, it is not required.
                'offline': true,
            },
            function(user_data) {
      // For the purpose of this example I will store user data on local storage
                alert('user data');
                alert(JSON.stringify(user_data));
            },
            function(msg) {
                alert('error block');
                alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
            }
        );

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consult "How to ask a good question" manual and update your question by adding relevant information. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See the end of answer why you get error 10: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159235/google-login-with-cordova-wont-work-error-10-in-android-and-bad-request-in-ios